# How to get inserted id for Adodb + oci8 in php

Tags: php, oracle, adodb, oci8

I am using ADODB in my Oracle databse with PHP

I am using some return query like this

```
INSERT into (...)
return id into :XX
```

**and it is working fine using normal oci8 drivers of PHP**

```
 $stmt = OCIParse($c, $strQuery);

    OCIBindByName($stmt, ':xx', $fieldval);

      $ok = OCIExecute($stmt);
```

But I want to execute same return query in ADODB How can I do this I tried lot of time but it is not return anything

Comment: Where is your ADOdb code ?

Comment: @SyedQarib In ADODB I don't know about Parsing I am just executing query .....

  return $this->DB->Execute($strQuery); 
Like this

Comment: Show the code man! What ever you are doing..

Comment: @SyedQarib, I got my answer Thanks.....I was confused......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I want ...

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO ALERTAS 
 (ALERTA_CONSECUTIVO,
  ALERTA_ID,
  ALERTA_FRECUENCIA,
  ALERTA_FEC_LEJ,
  ALERTA_FEC_CER,
  ALERTA_FEC_MIN,
  ALERTA_NOMBRE)
  VALUES (14,5,5,5,15,15,:Clob1)
  return ALERTA_ID into :XX";

$varChintan ='Chintandfhsdskjfsjd sdjhfb ';
                $stmt = $myDbObj->DB->PrepareSP($sql);

        $blob = $myDbObj->DB->InParameter($stmt, $varChintan, 'Clob1',1000000);
        $blob = $myDbObj->DB->InParameter($stmt, $returndata, 'xx');
        $myDbObj->DB->StartTrans();
        $ok = $myDbObj->DB->Execute($stmt);
        $myDbObj->DB->CompleteTrans();

echo $returndata;
```

Thanks @SyedQarib